# How do I convert multiple pdf's into a corpus for text analysis in R?

Tags: r, nlp, topic-modeling

I have a very basic question because I'm an absolute beginner. I've tried to find help online and read different tutorials and handbooks, but can't find the answer.

My project is very simple. I have dozens of pdf's (stored in a folder) that I want to analyse for their contents (unsupervised learning). The ultimate goal is a topic analysis. Now here's the problem: every guide I can find jumps right into pre-processing of these texts without going over the first steps of loading these files into R and defining the corpus.

So, basically, I want to break down all these pdf's in a dataframe for analysis but I'm missing the first step of loading these in R.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask] As a starting point: Have a look at the `pdftools` package on CRAN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways, but if you want to get it into a corpus there is a simple way to do it. It does require that the package pdftools is installed (`install.packages("pdftools")`) as that will be the engine used to read the pdfs. Then it is just a question of using the tm package to read everything into a corpus.

```
library(tm)

directory <- getwd() # change this to directory where files are located

# read the pdfs with readPDF, default engine used is pdftools see ?readPDF for more info
my_corpus <- VCorpus(DirSource(directory, pattern = ".pdf"), 
                               readerControl = list(reader = readPDF))
```

Comment: Thank you, this solves my question. However, a new question popped up because now I get the error: 'Error in inherits(x, "Source") : empty directory' when executing the last line.

Comment: the directory now points to your local R working directory. If there are not pdf's in there you will get this error as there are no documents to read. If you change directory to your directory where the pdf's are located the error will be gone. Something like `directory <- "D:/here are/my files"`

Comment: Thank you. I wanted to be a smart-ass and used setwd("mydirectory). Obviously I should learn to follow instructions. Case closed. Thank you very much